# How to implement post method in serverless 1.0?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-lambda

I'm getting an "no response from server" error in swagger, also lambda function don't triggers and I do not see any errors in cloudwatch, seems like I have a problem with YAML file in post method.
I spent 2 days trying to understand what is going on here with no result, so I would be grateful for any help!!
**my yaml file:**

```
pool-config:
handler: dest/functions/pool-config/handler.execute
events:
  - http:
      path: v1/config/pool
      method: post
      integration: lambda
      request:
         template:
            application/json: '{
              "body": "$input.json(''$'')",
              "functionAlias": "$stageVariables.functionAlias",
              "principalId": "$context.authorizer.principalId",
              "httpMethod": "$context.httpMethod"}'
      response:
         headers:
           Content-Type: "'application/json'"
           Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"          
         template: $input.path('$')
      cors:   
        origins:
          - '*'
        headers:
          - Content-Type 
          - X-Amz-Date
          - Authorization
      authorizer: authorizer
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!!!! The reason was in this line `"body": "$input.json(''$'')"` we should use it without quotes like this `"body": $input.json(''$'')`